# activerecord-reputation-system not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did a small project reference `Quick Start`, but when i accessed reputation value An error has occurred

`answer.reputation_for :avg_rating`

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/Juo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bundler/gems/activerecord-reputation-system-01197ad78cac/lib/reputation_system/models/reputation.rb:189:in `get_target_type_for_sti'
from /Users/Juo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bundler/gems/activerecord-reputation-system-01197ad78cac/lib/reputation_system/models/reputation.rb:198:in `set_target_type_for_sti'
from /Users/Juo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:377:in `_run__3152603553061474011__validation__callbacks'`
```

Someone help me?

> Let's say we want to keep track of user karma in Q&A site where user karma is sum of questioning skill and answering skill. Questioning skill is sum of votes for user's questions and Answering skill is sum of average rating of user's answers. This can be defined as follow:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_many :questions

  has_reputation :karma,
      :source => [
          { :reputation => :questioning_skill, :weight => 0.8 },
          { :reputation => :answering_skill }]

  has_reputation :questioning_skill,
      :source => { :reputation => :votes, :of => :questions }

  has_reputation :answering_skill,
      :source => { :reputation => :avg_rating, :of => :answers }
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :as => :author

  has_reputation :avg_rating,
      :source => :user,
      :aggregated_by => :average,
      :source_of => [{ :reputation => :answering_skill, :of => :author }]
end


class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_reputation :votes,
      :source => :user
end
```

Comment: You should post more code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove :as => :author from Answer model, and set :of => :user in the initialization of has_reputation :avg_rating.